# Identify surface points in a point cloud

Tags: math, point-clouds

imagine you have a point cloud of a 3D object, where you have points on the surface of the object as well as points from inside the object.

Is there a way to know which points lie on the surface, and which are inside if you don’t have that information?

I tried looking at how stl models do it but no luck!

Comment: Depends on exactly what the object is, but maybe something like convex hull would be a good starting point to explore ways of doing this

Comment: There is a ton of papers with names similar to "new method for surface detection in pointcloud". I suggest using a pointcloud library and finding what surface detection methods are already implemented in it. Unless this is a "I'd like to figure this out for fun" question, in which case you can either try something entirely yourself (for instance, a point on the inside will see points in all directions, whereas a point at a locally-convex location on the surface will only see points on one side of a tangent plane); or read some papers about existing methods.

Comment: Thank you both, it's something I need for work. Stef, your suggestion around points and directions sounds like a great start. I will give it a go.

Comment: The *alpha-hull* is a way to explore if the volume bounded by the surface is not convex.

Comment: Thanks Stephane! I added a paper on alpha-hull below in case anyone sees the discussion later.

https://hal.inria.fr/hal-03036810/file/alpha-hulls.pdf